# Set initial size and memorize last size of allotments

Tags: css, reactjs, panel

I have made a draggable split panel by https://github.com/johnwalley/allotment.

I would like to realize several things:

1. Clicking on `Expand or collapse the allotment B` will expand or collapse the allotment B.
2. We can drag the splitter, the position of the splitter is saved before collapsing the allotment B so that we can go back to that position when expanding allotment B.
3. The first time when we expand the allotment B, I would like the height of the allotment B to be 1/5 of the entire height.

I wrote the code as follows (https://codesandbox.io/s/reset-forked-f2f386?file=/src/App.js). I could not realize 2) and 3) at the same time.

Does anyone know why it's like that?

```
import React from "react";
import { Allotment } from "allotment";
import "allotment/dist/style.css";
import "./style.css";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      toExpand: true,
      lastExpandedSize: [200, 50]
    };
    this.myRef = React.createRef();
  }

  handleChangeAllotment = (sizes) => {
    if (sizes.length > 1) {
      if (sizes[1] < 31) {
        this.setState({ toExpand: true });
      } else {
        this.setState({
          toExpand: false,
          lastExpandedSize: sizes // removing this line will set the initial sizes correctly, but will not be able to save last sizes.
        });
      }
    }
  };

  undertakeExpandOrCollapse = () => {
    if (this.state.toExpand) {
      this.myRef.current.resize(this.state.lastExpandedSize);
    } else {
      this.myRef.current.resize([10000, 0]);
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        style={{
          minWidth: 200,
          height: "100vh",
          overflowX: "auto",
          width: "auto",
          margin: "0px 0px 0px 0px"
        }}
      >
        <Allotment
          vertical
          onChange={this.handleChangeAllotment}
          ref={this.myRef}
        >
          <Allotment.Pane>
            <span onClick={this.undertakeExpandOrCollapse}>
              Expand or collapse the allotment B
            </span>
          </Allotment.Pane>
          <Allotment.Pane preferredSize="0%" minSize={30}>
            the allotment B
          </Allotment.Pane>
        </Allotment>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My quick idea is that by default, there is no saved value, and the value of `lastExpandedSize` is `null`. Sensing this, we pass one-fifth of the screen height as the saved height. When closing, there will already be a saved value, so the `useState` function will return that value from then on.

```js
// ...

constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    toExpand: true,
    lastExpandedSize: null // set null to default
  };
  this.containerRef = React.createRef();
  this.myRef = React.createRef();
}

/**
 * Check to has LastExpandedSize
 * @return {bool}
 */
hasLastExpandedSize = () => {
  return this.state.lastExpandedSize !== null;
}

/**
 * Get DefaultExpandedSize
 * @param {number} ratio
 * @param {number} height
 * @return {number[]}
 */
getDefaultExpandedSize = (ratio = 5, height = 0) => {
  if (height < 1) {
    height = this.containerRef.current.clientHeight;
  }

  return [
    height * (ratio - 1) / ratio, 
    height / ratio
  ];
}

handleChangeAllotment = (sizes) => {
  if (sizes.length > 1) {
    if (sizes[1] < 31) {
      this.setState({ toExpand: true });
    }
    else {
      this.setState({
        toExpand: false,
        lastExpandedSize: this.hasLastExpandedSize()
          ? sizes
          : this.getDefaultExpandedSize()
      });
    }
  }
};

// ...
```

```html
<div
  ref={this.containerRef}
  style={{
    minWidth: 200,
    height: "100vh",
    overflowX: "auto",
    width: "auto",
    margin: "0px 0px 0px 0px"
  }}
>
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. One thing is that when we change the size of the screen, it seems that `getDefaultExpandedSize` with `document.body.scrollHeight` does not work well. We can hard code for instance `[2000, 500]`, it's the ratio that counts.

Comment: You are right in that I shouldn't have started with the height of the page. Let's look at the default height of the container element. In the codesandbox code you provided, both my previous and current examples work perfectly.

Comment: However, if you resize the page/container after the first expansion, it becomes a logical trap that it has already been opened once. Alternatively, you can set up a listener that detects changes in the height of the container element and deletes the saved dimensions in that case.